# Under what circumstances is a reverse for loop faster in Flash and why?

Tags: actionscript-3

According to Adobe, a reverse for loop is the fastest way to do a loop:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/optimizing-flash-performance.html

I could not create a test where a reverse for loop was consistently faster than a normal loop, but I'm assuming Adobe knows Flash. Does anyone know under what circumstance this is true and why?

Comment: This is typical distracting useless advice from Adobe. You'll probably have better luck long-run if you assume everything in Adobe's documentation is an elaborate lie intended to mess you up as much as possible. There are sections that look like they weren't even written by a programmer, let alone an ActionScript programmer.

Comment: I second @JeremyBanks - Adobe is really unreliable with their information, specifically when it comes to performance optimisations and 'tricks'. If you want real performance tests and comparisons, you should head over to [Jackson Dunstan's](http://jacksondunstan.com/) website which is amazing.

Comment: Not directly related to performance, but reverse loop can be convenient when you need to remove multiple items from a collection and don't want to mess your loop index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to recalculate the `length` of an array or Vector if you iterate backwards.

```
for(var i:int = list.length; i > 0; i--)
// -------------^^^^^^^^^^^ Length is calculated once for the start value.
```

Versus:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < list.length; i++)
// --------------------^^^^^^^^^^^ Length is calculated for each iteration.
```

FYI, the difference is speed is negligible. I personally use whichever is more readable to me (the former).

That aside - if you are iterating over a collection where all objects are of the same type, you should be using a `for each` loop. This is much faster, more readable and more logical than either of the above. The reason that it is faster is because no type conversion is required at each iteration - the type is set when you define the loop:

```
var strings:Array = ["a","b","c"];
for each(var i:String in strings)
{
    trace(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Marty is correct: if you use a reverse for loop you have to get the length value only once. However, this can be easily achieved through a normal for loop, and assigning the length to a variable beforehand.

A further optimized reverse for loop would look like:

```
for(var i:int = list.length; i--;)
```

which results in looping through every element in the array in reverse without a third for loop argument.

Comment: It's important to note that 'optimized' and 'shortened' are not the same thing.